# Quaternion to Euler angles algorithm - How to convert to 'Y = Up' and between handedness?

Tags: c#, math, quaternions

I have an algorithm for converting between a Quaternion and Euler angles.

```
    public static Vector3 ToEulerAngles(this Quaternion q)
    {
        // Store the Euler angles in radians
        Vector3 pitchYawRoll = new Vector3();

        double sqw = q.W * q.W;
        double sqx = q.X * q.X;
        double sqy = q.Y * q.Y;
        double sqz = q.Z * q.Z;

        // If quaternion is normalised the unit is one, otherwise it is the correction factor
        double unit = sqx + sqy + sqz + sqw;
        double test = q.X * q.Y + q.Z * q.W;

        if (test > 0.4999f * unit)                              // 0.4999f OR 0.5f - EPSILON
        {
            // Singularity at north pole
            pitchYawRoll.Y = 2f * (float)Math.Atan2(q.X, q.W);  // Yaw
            pitchYawRoll.X = PI * 0.5f;                         // Pitch
            pitchYawRoll.Z = 0f;                                // Roll
            return pitchYawRoll;
        }
        else if (test < -0.4999f * unit)                        // -0.4999f OR -0.5f + EPSILON
        {
            // Singularity at south pole
            pitchYawRoll.Y = -2f * (float)Math.Atan2(q.X, q.W); // Yaw
            pitchYawRoll.X = -PI * 0.5f;                        // Pitch
            pitchYawRoll.Z = 0f;                                // Roll
            return pitchYawRoll;
        }
        else
        {
            pitchYawRoll.Y = (float)Math.Atan2(2f * q.Y * q.W - 2f * q.X * q.Z, sqx - sqy - sqz + sqw);       // Yaw
            pitchYawRoll.X = (float)Math.Asin(2f * test / unit);                                             // Pitch
            pitchYawRoll.Z = (float)Math.Atan2(2f * q.X * q.W - 2f * q.Y * q.Z, -sqx + sqy - sqz + sqw);      // Roll
        }

        return pitchYawRoll;
    }
```

This method only works for a right-handed Cartesian coordinate system with the Z axis pointing up.

What would I change in order to make the Y axis point up instead of Z? (Would swapping X and Z work?)

How can I accommodate left handed coordinate systems?

EDIT:

```
public static Quaternion CreateFromYawPitchRoll(float yaw, float pitch, float roll)
{
float num = roll * 0.5f;
float num2 = (float)Math.Sin((double)num);
float num3 = (float)Math.Cos((double)num);
float num4 = pitch * 0.5f;
float num5 = (float)Math.Sin((double)num4);
float num6 = (float)Math.Cos((double)num4);
float num7 = yaw * 0.5f;
float num8 = (float)Math.Sin((double)num7);
float num9 = (float)Math.Cos((double)num7);
Quaternion result;
result.X = num9 * num5 * num3 + num8 * num6 * num2;
result.Y = num8 * num6 * num3 - num9 * num5 * num2;
result.Z = num9 * num6 * num2 - num8 * num5 * num3;
result.W = num9 * num6 * num3 + num8 * num5 * num2;
return result;
}
```

Comment: Quaternions and euler angles are independent of the alignment of the coordinate system and of the headedness. Yaw, pitch and roll define rotations about the z, y and x axis respecitvely. It does not matter, how the axes are oriented.

Comment: If I use this in combination with XNA's Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll then I do not get the original Quaternion though.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.quaternion.createfromyawpitchroll.aspx

Comment: Then the functions probably use different associations of yaw/pitch/roll to the axes. Swap the euler angles, so the definitions match .

Comment: Could you please post an example based on the EDIT I have made which now includes the Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are changed methods that use the same definition of yaw, pitch, roll:

```
public static Quaternion CreateFromYawPitchRoll(float yaw, float pitch, float roll)
{
    float rollOver2 = roll * 0.5f;
    float sinRollOver2 = (float)Math.Sin((double)rollOver2);
    float cosRollOver2 = (float)Math.Cos((double)rollOver2);
    float pitchOver2 = pitch * 0.5f;
    float sinPitchOver2 = (float)Math.Sin((double)pitchOver2);
    float cosPitchOver2 = (float)Math.Cos((double)pitchOver2);
    float yawOver2 = yaw * 0.5f;
    float sinYawOver2 = (float)Math.Sin((double)yawOver2);
    float cosYawOver2 = (float)Math.Cos((double)yawOver2);
    Quaternion result;
    result.X = cosYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2 + sinYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2;
    result.Y = cosYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2 - sinYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2;
    result.Z = cosYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2 + sinYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2;
    result.W = sinYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2 - cosYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2;
    return result;
}
```

For `ToEulerAngles` (singularities ommitted):

```
pitchYawRoll.Y = (float)Math.Atan2(2f * q.X * q.W + 2f * q.Y * q.Z, 1 - 2f * (sqz  + sqw));     // Yaw 
pitchYawRoll.X = (float)Math.Asin(2f * ( q.X * q.Z - q.W * q.Y ) );                             // Pitch 
pitchYawRoll.Z = (float)Math.Atan2(2f * q.X * q.Y + 2f * q.Z * q.W, 1 - 2f * (sqy + sqz));      // Roll
```

I performed the following test:

```
var q = CreateFromYawPitchRoll(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.7f);
var e = ToEulerAngles(q);
var q2 = CreateFromYawPitchRoll(e.Y, e.X, e.Z);
```

with the following results;

```
e = (0.3, 0.2, 0.7) //pitch, yaw, roll
q2 = q
```

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles)

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks.  Are the singularities correct as originally written?

Comment: `if (test > 0.4999f * unit)                              // 0.4999f OR 0.5f - EPSILON
            {
                // Singularity at north pole
                pitchYawRoll.Y = 2f * (float)Math.Atan2(q.Y, q.W);  // Yaw
                pitchYawRoll.X = PI * 0.5f;                         // Pitch
                pitchYawRoll.Z = 0f;                                // Roll
                return pitchYawRoll;
            }`

Comment: Just checked, PI does not produce the correct results.  For example  `FromYawPitchRoll((float)Math.PI, 0f, 0f)`

Comment: `test` has to be `= q.X * q.Z - q.W * q.Y`. However, I am not absolutely sure, about the singularity values. You're best off trying it out.

Comment: That equation for 'test' can't be correct.  It produces a value of 0 for both (0, 0, 0) and (PI, 0, 0).

Comment: Singularities occur if pitch is -PI or +Pi, regardless of what yaw is.

Comment: The problem is that the equation for test doesn't produce a result of 0.5 or -0.5 for the singularity so I can't test for it.  It produces an answer of 0 for both singularity and Identity.

Comment: Necro, but, the problem is that test approaches unit/2 at an increasingly slow rate. It is not a good metric with which to test. It is also guaranteed to never go above unit/2. The thing we really care about are the inputs to the atan2 functions. A test such as `if kSinY*kSinY + kCosY*kCosY < 0.00000001` is better suited to solving this problem.